# How to download a FaceBook user photo

Tags: c++, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-x

I use to use CCHttpRequest(cocos2dx) to request a photo from internet and it works for URL like "https://www.baidu.com/img/bdlogo.png".

However I can't download the FB friend photo by CCHttpRequest. The photo URL is "https://graph.facebook.com/1386570461651640/picture…"
Furthermore I tried NSRequest(OC). It worked for this URL and downloaded the photo.

So, anyone knows how to download friends photo by CCHttpRequest or any other method which works in *.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
    string _id = "" // id require to whome you want to fectch photo
        HttpRequest* request = new (std::nothrow) HttpRequest();
            string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+_id+"/picture?height=120
                    &width=120";
            request->setUrl(url.c_str());
            request->setRequestType(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest::Type::GET);
            request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(HellowWorld::onRequestImgCompleted, this));
            request->setTag("GetImage");
            HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
            request->release();



void HellowWorld::onRequestImgCompleted(HttpClient *sender, HttpResponse *response)
{

    log("AppDelegate::onHttpRequestCompleted - onHttpRequestCompleted BEGIN");
    if (!response)
    {
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - No Response");
        return;
    }

    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %lu", response->getResponseCode());

    if (!response->isSucceed())
    {
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response failed");
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
        return;
    }
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %s", response->getResponseDataString());

    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();

    Image * image = new  Image ();
    image-> initWithImageData ( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&(buffer->front())), buffer->size());
    Texture2D * texture = new  Texture2D ();
    texture-> initWithImage (image);
    Sprite* sp = Sprite::createWithTexture(texture);
    add(sp);
    sp->setPosition(Vec2(100, 100));
}
```